# How to use callback of setState()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, state

I'm trying to use callback of setState() in order to check that the state was changed correctly. However, I get an error `Expected 1 arguments, but got 2`.

```
   setCurrentLength(300, () => {
      console.log('Current length ', currentLength);
   });
```

How to solve it?
Thanks

Comment: `setState` returned as the second part of the tuple from the `useState` hook does not have this feature. The callback function you are attempting to use is part of `this.setState` found in a class Component.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using the callback for [setState](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate). But you are using [useState](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate) hook.

Use should use [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate) for this with dependency array, so when ever `currentLength` is changed your `console.log` will be executed.

```
useEffect(()=>{
  console.log('Current length ', currentLength);
}, [currentLength]);
```